# How to remove/close bootstrap css notification?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hide

I'm trying to use [this css example](http://cssdeck.com/labs/twitter-bootstrap-alerts-and-notifications) for notifications in my website. In the example, the cross on the right seems to suggest that the notification can be closed, but this is not working for me. Does anybody know how I can make this cross close the notification (preferably using just html/css instead of Javascript)?

All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
</button>
    <strong>Warning!</strong> Better check yourself, you're not looking too good.
</div>
```

This is a pure css solution, here is the example on the [bootstrap site](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts-examples).

Comment: Awesome! I didn't see this one before. That looks way more awesome!

Answer (score 1):

*but this is not working for me* - Won't work for anyone, because there is no code written to close those notification boxes.

You will have to use JS or jQuery inorder to close the notification bar, here am using jQuery to close the notification boxes ...

```
$('a.close').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

[**Demo**](http://cssdeck.com/labs/irtlelw3)

Here, am attaching a `click` event to anchor tag with a `class` of `.close` and `on click` am hiding the parent element of the notification bar, which is nothing but a `div` tag with a shared `class` of `alert-message`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are having following files linked to your project

> bootstrap.min.js

and then add this script to your page!

```
 $('a.close').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't add interactivity using only HTML/CSS to the html element.
So use jQuery or pure JavaScript
Using JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("myP1").style.display="none";
```

OR
use `document.getElementById("myP2").style.visibility="hidden";//this will effect the layout`